# How to get an encfs mount on the Unity launcher?

Tags: unity, launcher, mount

I've created a `encfs` mount on my home and I am starting it automatically with `gnome-encfs`, however there is no icon on the unity dock, but instead there is a icon on the desktop.

I would rather have it on the dock since it seems more natural as it happens with USB sticks, CD roms, DVDs, etc...

Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea for the launcher but I use the Ubuntu AppIndicator `CryptFolder-Indicator`.

You can find an introduction at http://www.webupd8.org/2011/06/cryptfolder-indicator-ubuntu.html.

Cheers